# HTML5 - When button is pressed open a window with options

Tags: html, button, checkbox, prompt

At the moment i have a normal button:

`<a href="" class="button">Sign up</a>`

Instead of sending it to a link immediatly i want it to display a popup window with mutliple options like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prompt

But instead of the textbox i would like it to display checkboxes with the site it will direct you to. (and you can only select one checkbox)

Quick example i made in paint:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/s5cvu1.jpg

Not sure if this is possible since i'm not experienced with working on websites.

Comment: Consider using a jquery ui modal for the popup, then treating that like aform

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and I don't think SO is here to give you a tutorial but as a help for you to get started I suggest you check out window.open event that you will need to fire in order to open a pop up http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp then on the pop up window you will have to decide whether it's better to have a checkbox or a radiobutton, since you want that only one option is ticked and so on. I suggest you look on google for "pop ups getting started" and javascript. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick method:

```
 <a href="" class="button" onclick=Login(); >Sign up</a>
```

again define the method signup in Scrpt tag

```
 <script>
Login()
{
}

 </script>
```

For better understanding refer this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick

This is very simple example, alternatively, if u r aware of jquery, it will make your work very easy, going for jquery is better option.
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/